# Model relationship in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have 2 controllers & Models:

1. User Controller: (Model Relationship: `$this->hasMany(Hero::Class);`)
2. Hero Controller: Each hero has his own attributes, such as name, strength and life.
   Model Relationship: (`$this->belongsTo(User::class);`)

Each user can own multiple heroes.

that means that `USER ID: 1` may have 3 heroes: `HERO ID 5, 20, 26.`.

My question: How to define the relationships like that and make laravel knows how to handle my `user_heroes` table?
The relationship i'm talking about is described in the following image:

[image: Despired relationship]

How to I setup such kind of relationship in my laravel API?

Comment: Yes, I do mean that.

Comment: It seems to me what you want is a one-to-many relationship, but your database doesn't reflect that relationship. You need a pivot table in the case of a many-to-many relationship. If you want to have a one-to-many relationship, you need a `user_id` field in your `hero` table, you don't need a pivot table. That's how laravel expects you to set up your database for this kind of relationship.

Comment: Hmm.. when I think about it, ONE user can own multiple heroes but I will still have to use the "many to many" relationship logic. I added an image to be more descriptive of what I'm trying to reach.  Can you confrim that although one user can have multiple heroes(which means one to many) I'll still have to use the many to many relationship in laravel?

Comment: Can more than one user own the same hero?  Eg can user id 2 also have hero id 5?

Comment: Yes, he can also have hero 5. @Don'tPanic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a User can have many heroes, and a Hero can also belong to many users, it is a many to many relationship.  In Laravel the inverse of a many to many relationship is also a many to many relationship, and they are both described by `belongsToMany()`.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

So in your User model:

```
public function heros() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Hero::class);
}
```

And in your Hero model:

```
public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}
```

Laravel will assume the joining table is named `hero_user`, the 2 model names, singular, joined in alphabetical order.  If you want to use `user_heroes` as you have in your image, you need to specify it:

```
return $this->belongsToMany(Hero::class, 'user_heroes');
```

(in both model methods).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. seem like I had to use many to many relationship. Do you know what's the expression to create a new user hero (assuming the user has logged in) in this case?

Comment: Something like `$user->heros()->attach($hero_id)`, if the hero already exists.  https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#inserting-many-to-many-relationships